# Unable to resolve java.io.InputStream dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am suddenly unable to resolve a "java.io.InputStream" dependency since Sunday (July 26, 2020), until then the dependency resolved.  I've checked Maven Central and found "No Results" in response to my search.  The java.io.InputStream documentation does not indicate the jar is deprecated.

Any one have an idea why the jar suddenly is unresolvable?

Comment: That class is an integral part of the jdk. Check your project setup, whether your code is pointing to a valid jdk

Answer (score 1):

Resolved -- my Ubuntu 20.04 jdk became corrupted somehow....